# Does Automatic Differentiation handle conditional branches, if yes how?

Tags: numerical-analysis, computer-algebra

I'm trying to understand how [Automatic Differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_derivatives) (AD) works.
For simple algebraic operation, I get the chain rule thing.
But, when the code contains conditional statement like

```
1: test_sign = x*y < 0
2: if test_sign :
3:     biggest = max(x,y)
4: else
5:     smallest = min(x,y)
```

Does AD work?
If it works, can you explain why?

When the code executes line 1, how does AD interpret the inequality `<`?
Let's say, my AD is in foward mode, what is the differential for the `if then else` branch?

My understanding is that the above code use non differentiable function, in the sense that left and right derivatives are not the same. So, how does AD pick the good derivative?

Also, if I'm in forward mode, it is possible that line 5 is never visited. But when AD bumps `x` to `x+h`, line 5 should be evaluated. So the AD tape will incorrectly always differentiate line 3, instead of differentiation line 5.

Comment: If your function behaves differently for different parts of your domain, shouldn't AD just use the same if-else? That's how I would implement it...

Comment: @adrianN When I wrote the question I had in mind, a library for AD, like ADOL-C. Your comment makes sense, so if I have an if-else, it's better if I handle this part of the AD myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping and branching with Algorithmic Differentiation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70615/looping-and-branching-with-algorithmic-differentiation)